# Sum array objects by array object key

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, sum

I have a list of my own class:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, oscis, cicin, zapl, odmdr, odmcas, odmnj, odmzak):
        self.oscis = oscis
        self.cicin = cicin
        self.zapl = zapl
        self.odmdr = odmdr
        self.odmcas = odmcas
        self.odmnj = odmnj
        self.odmzak = odmzak
```

My code reads CSV file and appends data to list of my class called Line:

```
temp = []
r = open(input_file, "r")
try:
    reader = csv.reader(r, delimiter = ";")
    for row in reader:
        temp.append(Line(row[0], "0", "01082015", "13", float(row[1].replace(",", ".").replace(" ", "")), float(row[2].replace(",", ".").replace(" ", "")), "13"))
finally:
    r.close()
```

Works so far so good. I have filled list with values from CSV file.

CSV file contains "oscis" which is key. I need sum "odmcas" and "odmnj" of every element of an array which have same "oscis" and create only one record.

Output when I print array by:

```
for l in temp:
    print(l.oscis, l.cicin, l.zapl, l.odmdr, l.odmcas, l.odmnj, l.odmzak)
```

is:

```
3031 0 01082015 13 25.0 10.0 13
3031 0 01082015 13 25.0 10.0 13
3031 0 01082015 13 0.5 0.5 13
```

Output from python script should be (summed "odmcas" and "odmnj" by "oscis" key):

```
3031 0 01082015 13 50.5 20.5 13
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `3031 0 01082015 13 50.5 20.5 13` ? Also, is the list already sorted using `oscis` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Output should be 3031 0 01082015 13 50.5 20.5 13 and yes, input CSV file is already sorted by oscis so array will be too.

Comment: What about other attributes?

Comment: They are constants as you can see in temp.append(...) and they should not be summed. Only "odmcas" and "odmnj" should be summed if their "oscis" is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this based on element's `.oscis` attribute and then for each group sum the two required attributes.

Please note, `itertools.groupby` requires the list to already be sorted based on the `key` on which you are going to group, so if the list is not already sorted you should sort it as -

```
tempsorted = sorted(temp, key=lambda x: x.oscis)
```

If the array is already sorted, then the above is not needed, you can directly use `temp` instead of `tempsorted` below -

```
import itertools
for k, grp in itertools.groupby(tempsorted, key=lambda x: x.oscis):
    summedodmcas = 0
    summedodmnj = 0
    for li in grp:
        summedodmcas += li.odmcas
        summedodmnj += li.odmnj
    print(li.oscis, li.cicin, li.zapl, li.odmdr, summedodmcas, summedodmnj, li.odmzak)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You taught me new thing today. Works exactly as I need.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.